How to "manually" map from WASM to source code with DWARF file
I am using Emscripten to compile C++ source code into WASM modules. I am compiling with several debug settings and am able to get the module to print out the line number in the WASM where the error occured. For example, when an exception occurs I see https://127.0.0.1:8081/clientScene.wasm+0xc8a3, I assume the +0xc8a3 is some reference for the line number the DWARF files can use. Normally you can use Chrome Canary to automatically map that location to the source file. However, I am developing on Linux and Chrome Canary is not available for Linux. Is there some tool I can use in conjunction with the generated DWARF files to get the source code line number?
I would like a tool that I can give a DWARF file and location in the compiled WASM and will give me the location in the source code.

The mechanism is generally addr2line, and wasm-tools has a set of tools around this, one of which should perform the same thing.

I think that repo is what I'm looking for. Thank you!
